# How to post list item dynamically from client side - MERN

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, user-interface, mongoose-schema, mern

I am trying to build a MERN stack app with a theme of recipe books, I am not able to finalize the logic of recipe schema. The app is about a recipe's where people will post their recipes publicly, so the recipe has to be build dynamically. I need some advice or suggestion on how to map things. Here are the details of my app.

Recipe Schema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        nameOfRecipe:{ // Title 
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 32
        },
        description: { // Short description
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 32
        },
        category: { // This will populate from another schema
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
            required: true
        },
        ingredientName: { // Ingredient title
            type: String, 
            maxlength: 25 
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number, // Ingredient Quantity
            default: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 9999
        },
        type:{
            type: String, // Ingredient type example: lb/kg/cups/tbsp
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 10
        },
        photo: { // image
            data: Buffer,
            contentType: String
        },
        method: { // Steps to cook
            type: String,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 2000
        },
        people: { // Number of people suggested to be served
            type: Number
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Recipe", recipeSchema);
```

I am not satisfied in my Schema too as I want the ingredient display as example "80grm Whole wheat flour" but with the schema I created above have all three as different properties and key values whereas it has to be displayed as one single string. How is this possible?

I want a UI similar to this...

[image: Sample Look]

Like how the "Ingredient" are in bullet and the "Instructions" in ordered list. But the issue is how is this possible from client side. 
Please advice....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ingredients and instructions must be array.

So you need can create embedded schemas for ingredients and instructions like this:
(note that I removed some fields for simplicity, and renamed method fiel to instructions which makes more sense)

```js
const ingredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ingredientName: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 25
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 9999
  },
  type: {
    type: String, // Ingredient type example: lb/kg/cups/tbsp
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 10
  }
});

const instructionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  order: Number,
  step: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 2000
  }
});

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nameOfRecipe: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32
    },
    ingredients: [ingredientSchema],
    instructions: [instructionSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: @Zeba ingredientSchema and instructionSchema  schemas are embedded schemas, so don't create model for these schemas, you will have only one model which is Recipe.

Comment: Yup.. Got it :)